# Type of constant expressions in Java

Tags: java

Why the bar with `int i` signature is called?

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    bar(5);  // What type of the integer "5"?
  }

  public static void bar(short i) { 
    System.out.println("short");
  }

  public static void bar(int i) { 
    System.out.println("int");    
  }

  public static void bar(long i) { 
    System.out.println("long");
  }
}
```

I've checked the Oracle's documents [15.12. Method Invocation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) and [15.28. Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), while still have no idea.

Could someone explain the type of the `constants expression`? Like the type of "5" above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you write a plain literal integer, it is always assumed to be of type `int`, unless you specify otherwise by casting it to another type, or by adding postfix `l` for `long`, `f` for `float`. For example:

```
long    →   1234l
float   →   25f
short   →   (short)5
double  →   (double)25
```

Answer (score 0):

5 is an Integer Literal. Since you already have a copy of the JLS, here is the relevant section.

> 3.10.1 Integer Literals - An integer literal may be expressed in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8), or binary (base 2).
>
> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell);
> otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear... that being said when you write a number in simple form (ex: 5, 6, 105, 20) it is automatically an `int`. If you wanted it to be `short` or `long` you would have to declare it, like so:

```
short s = 5
```

or

```
long l = 5
```